# 980 px wrapper not centering on Ipad

Tags: css, ipad

I've trying to get a simple wrapper div with a colored background to center on the iPad, right to left so it kisses both sides of the browser. My code is below. The wrapper isn't centering. It begins 10 pixels in from the left side of the window. There must be a simple answer to this but I can't seem to grasp what I'm doing wrong. Can you help?

```
<style type="text/css">
   <!--
    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width:980px;
        height:980px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#666666;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        This is a test
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which ipad are you using? If it is the older model the width of the screen is only 768px. Secondly add `display:block` to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the <!-- which is the start tag for a comment in html. I'm afraid it could mess up the css

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your css codes, try this codes:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width:980px;
        height:980px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:#666666;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

If it does not work, I do not have another idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width:980px;
        height:980px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#666666;
    }
</style>


<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        This is a test
    </div>
</body>
```

Are you missing `<!DOCTYPE` declaration? Additionally add  `<meta name="viewport" content="" />` for better results.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem right now - old Wordpress site, left aligned in iPad for some reason, no validation errors, standard CSS auto margin on wrapper to center as above.

Fixed using browser reset CSS, I used [Normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).